# top keyword in oracle 9i

Tags: keyword

what is the format for using top keyword in oracle 9i? i have to retreive top 10 records..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select column1,column2 from tbl1 where rownum<=10

Answer (score 2):

Use the RANK function as in...

```
select
   *
from
   (select empno,sal,rank()
    over (order by sal desc ) rnk
    from emp)
where rnk <= 5;
```

query was taken from [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/oracle_faq/faq_beg_sql_top_n_rows.htm)

Comment: +1 for solution that works with Oracle 9i.  ROWNUM is not supported in 9i.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [rownum keyword](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html)

```
SELECT * FROM (your ordered query)  WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```